# Global Css Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

How do I make a global CSS for all views in laravel?

I created my project by command

`composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 8.0 --prefer-dist`

Answer (score 2):

You just create a layout and include the public/app.css in the HTML head. Read about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#defining-a-layout

PS: Are you sure you want to base your project on Laravel 4.2?

Comment: lol, I was 4.2 there because I caught the command on the net